# Read from multiple tables in vb.net data reader

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datareader, mysql-error-1052

I'm trying to read from two tables in mysql:

```
Dim sqlcom As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("Select * from  mother, father where IDNO= '" & TextBox14.Text & "' ", sqlcon)
```

-But I get this error:

```
Column 'IDNO' in where clause is ambiguous
```

Here is the whole code:

```
Dim NoAcc As String
        Dim NoAccmod2 As String
        Dim NoPas As String

        Dim sqlcon As New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; Database=school;Uid=root;Pwd=nitoryolai123$%^;")
        Dim sqlcom As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("Select * from  mother, father where IDNO= '" & TextBox14.Text & "' ", sqlcon)

        sqlcon.Open()


        Dim rdr As MySqlDataReader
        rdr = sqlcom.ExecuteReader


        If rdr.HasRows Then
            rdr.Read()
            NoAcc = rdr("IDNO")
            If (TextBox14.Text = NoAcc) Then TextBox7.Text = rdr("MOTHER")
            If (TextBox14.Text = NoAcc) Then TextBox8.Text = rdr("MOTHER_OCCUPATION")
            If (TextBox14.Text = NoAcc) Then TextBox10.Text = rdr("FATHER")
            If (TextBox14.Text = NoAcc) Then TextBox11.Text = rdr("FATHER_OCCUPATION")
        End If
```

-Any suggestions that could help solve this problem?
Or even other techniques on achieving the goal of reading data from two tables using data reader?

This is a winform, not a web form

Comment: FYI, your code is subject to SQL injection attacks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on your command:

```
Dim sqlcom As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("Select * from  mother, father where mother.IDNO= '" & TextBox14.Text & "' AND father.IDNO = '" & TextBox14.Text  & "'", sqlcon)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the schema of your tables I can't say for certain, but I'd guess your ID columns are named the same in both tables.  To get around that, you're going to need to fully qualify the one you're looking for, by using mother.IDNO or father.IDNO (or mother.IDNO AND father.IDNO).

Comment: Barry's right. The issue has nothing to do with .NET, rather it's the query. If you issued the same query in Management Studio or LINQpad you'd see the same error.

Comment: right, I get the same error when I query it on mysql, what would be the correct query?

Answer (score 0):

If (TextBox14.Text = NoAcc) Then TextBox7.Text = rdr("MOTHER")

If (TextBox14.Text = NoAcc) Then TextBox8.Text = rdr("MOTHER_OCCUPATION")

If (TextBox14.Text = NoAcc) Then TextBox10.Text = rdr("FATHER")

If (TextBox14.Text = NoAcc) Then TextBox11.Text = rdr("FATHER_OCCUPATION")

Looks rather redundant/inefficient doesn't it?

Also you might try using an INNER JOIN instead of dual IDNO "Where"s